Error: 1297 Print Spooler service failed to start. A privilage that the service requires to function properly doesnot exist
I am trying to start Print Spooler service as a Logon user but I am getting an error
The Print Spooler service failed to start due to the following reason:
A privilage that the service requires to funtion properly doesnot exist in the service account configuration. You may use Services Microsoft Management Console and local Security Settings to view the service configuration and account configuration.
I checked the solution here: A privilege that the service requires to start doesn't exist in the Service Account
Added the AD user to Local Security Policy. However, I am still unable to start the service.
This is the user 
and I have also added this user under Local Security Policy 
Still can't get the service to run.

Please list the specific things that you have tried in the question. Also, ChatGPT is no use unless you already have an idea what you're looking for. It will imagine fake solutions and unless you know what to look for, you'll be too easily duped by it. For this and other reasons we on this site to not consider "looking at chatgpt" to be a very legitimate effort to self-solve.

This question is similar to: A privilege that the service requires to start doesn't exist in the Service Account. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I made some changes to my question above. All I am trying to do is start the Print Spooler service on the server as a Logon user. However, I am unable to start and getting the same error.
